# webpages_xxx tables in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a newly created MVC4 project'd database tables, I don't know how can I insert the data for default built-in tables like `webpages_OAuthMembership` `webpages_Roles` and `webpages_UsersInRoles`. 
When I register a new account, only the other two tables not mentioned above are in use; I wonder if I have to manually edit the rest 3 tables while inside webpages_OAuthMembership, I don't understand what Provider means.

Comment: A great place to start is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check this article
 http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx